# DIBS SSL Payment

Tags: ssl, callback, payment, dibs

I am implementing payment in my app and my payment provider (DIBS) has problems connecting to my server with callback string. I send their server a callback string, and this string has to be forwarded to my server to confirm the payment has gone through. The problem is that the payment providers server can not communicate with my server. They have retrieved the following error message from their logs:

```
Callback - CURL-ERR:ERR 100: Network communication error: 
Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to rothausendev.dk:1080 Callback(effectiveURL): 
https://rothausendev.dk/AppBookingManage/Confirm/51afef3208ec40af73fb89682b9cd75d313b5dd6 
returns curl errornumber: 35
```

We have SSL with TLS procotol enabled on our server, and we have confirmed that   port 443 (this port is used for communication with https) is open. Anybody has an idea what the error in their logs can mean, and how I should set up my server to avoid the error?

Comment: try formatting your question for better readability and remove your actual links (provide dummy links). And don't forget to get specific help for your code add your code

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with our certificate and apparently DIBS does NOT support 4096-bit encryption for the callback URL.